# Can we change the working of mantras?

Tags: mantras

I would like to know whether we can change the working of mantras. For example, some mantras give fortune (wealth), some give good marriage life etc when chanted. Now, my question is whether we can change the result of a mantra to attain a specific desire by telling to the god or otherwise read a mantra without taking any results from it.

For example, can anyone read a mantra but resist results from it? Also, can anyone read one mantra and get another benefit from it? If so how?

Comment: Once can not resist the fruits of their work. be it good or bad. One does not have any ways to deny or object or resist it.... just accept it and move on.
What you asking is to attain a specific result.... that's not easy...One does not ask for anything from god.... god has created this universe and all the necessities that a human being requires....all we need to do is go out there and get your fair share of it, but not others share....

Comment: mantra is like a radio station. by saying the mantra one is tuning His mental antenna to that particular Divine Radio Station. By proper tuning one is able to obtain the exact channel that one desires. How to attain that tuning, proper concentration and focus is key. Proper pronunciation is second. With these two it becomes possible to attune one to these vibrations that enable/disable/reduce specific results/karma from functioning. can one change working? yes & no. no because the mantra is set in meaning & purpose. Yes because in reality (Advaita) it's all ur imagination nothing is set

Answer (score 6):

Mantras are based on sound (vibration). If the mantra is pronounced correctly it will create a certain vibration and that vibration sets in motion actions that deliver a certain result.

You cannot `change` a mantra to do something else. All mantras must be pronounced correctly to deliver the correct result. If not pronounced correctly, some mantras will not deliver any result. Some mantras if not pronounced correctly will deliver harmful results.

Think of when a song is sung. When it is done by a well trained voice, it can create subtle good feelings in those that hear it. Obversely, when the same song is sung by someone that is say, tone deaf, people turn away in pain. Same song, different vibrations being generated.

There's no `magic` involved.

Comment: What about reading the mantra and resisting results from it?

Comment: Hi, Can someone please tell me how can one understand what mantra he need? Can't it be possible that only taking one mantra for "Japa" one does not need to know other mantras? Please tell me.

Comment: @parthTrivedi mantra given at diksha initiation for japam is directed towards your ishta and is for moksha. It will help you towards moksha, not towards worldly gains. Your japam mantra has the vibration that is most effective in helping you towards moksha. Mantras in the question above are for worldly gain.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda okey, Now what I am asking you is "Should one change a mantra for japa?" Because I do not know which mantra is my isht deva's mantra. I actually do not know anything about Mantra Theory for "Japa". Can one chanting Om Ramay Namah , can switch to "Om Namah Shivay", just without reason. No gains, no stories. Just change of mantra without any worldly desire?

Comment: @parthtrivedi mantras he needs are in the vedas. Many in the atharva veda. Brahmins are experts in this. There are many depending upon what exactly you want, i.e., wealth, or success in trade, or prosperity? win love of a woman or for marriage or for birth of a child or what? Different mantras for each. Brhamins can help with this.

Comment: @parthtrivedi if you do not have diksha mantra from guru, then whatever name of God that your heart finds attractive is ok. And you can change, no problem; just don't jump around all the time.

Comment: @javatechnical reading in English, ok; mantras need to be recited in Sanskrit to be effective.